# Report writing: should I use ® © symbols?

Tags: technical-writing, citations, academic-writing, software, research

I am busy writing a report for university.

For this, I did some programming in MATLAB and simulations in Aspen Plus and HYSYS.

When referring to these software in the report, should I symbols such as  ® /© next to their names?

Comment: what does your university's style guide say?

Comment: Good question!

But I do not see anything about that in the guide

Comment: You could find out what other report writers have done and suggest an entry to your university's style guide. In that case, the suggestion in [Kitkhain's answer](http://writers.stackexchange.com/a/19355/26) might be a good way to go.

Comment: I have sent an email to the librarian and am waiting on her response

Answer (score 3):

The CHICAGO MANUAL OF STYLE recommends excluding them except in situations where it is legally required (e g., paid, competitive advertising or if you work for the company).

Comment: I agree, and add a supporting argument: In many fonts, the characters ® and © are not really matching the font in general, and can draw much visual attention - to something with no relevance to the reader at all. That makes it kind of "look ugly" with some fonts.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that says it is bad to include them. It's not really required for more common writing. If you aren't following a specific journal format it's acceptable to use the symbol the first time you introduce the brand then you can drop it off the next time to use it or you can use it every time you mention the brand. It's really your preference.

Comment: I have sent an email to the librarian and am waiting on her response.

For now I am just going to use it the first time I mention the software. Thanks